# testing if a shared_ptr is NULL

Tags: c++, null, shared-ptr

I have the following code snippet:

```
std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<Foo> >::iterator it;
it = returnsAnIterator();
// often, it will point to a shared_ptr that is NULL, and I want to test for that
if(*it)
{
    // do stuff
}
else // do other stuff
```

Am I testing correctly?  The boost docs say that a shared_ptr can be implicitly converted to a bool, but when I run this code it segfaults:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0806c252 in boost::shared_ptr<Foo>::operator Foo*
boost::shared_ptr<Foo>::* (this=0x0)
    at /usr/local/bin/boost_1_43_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/operator_bool.hpp:47
47              return px == 0? 0: &this_type::px;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are testing it correctly.

Your problem, however, is likely caused by dereferencing an invalid iterator. Check that `returnsAnIterator()` always returns an iterator that is not `vector.end()` and the vector is not modified in between, or empty.

Comment: The iterator is `vector.begin()`, so apparently I was testing the wrong thing.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the code you have above is correct.  `shared_ptr` can be implicitly converted to a bool to check for null-ness.

The problem you have is your `returnAnIterator()` function is returning an invalid iterator.  Probably it is returning `end()` for some container, which is one *past* the end of the container, and thus cannot be dereferenced as you're doing with `*it`.