# C++ Automatically detecting where shared_ptr is compared to NULL

Tags: c++, boost, null, shared-ptr

We have a large legacy codebase with commonly referenced pointer types that are, for various reasons, better suited to being shared_ptrs.

shared_ptrs are nice drop-in replacements for regular pointers except for NULL checks.
Throughout the code we have regular NULL checks on these pointers and after conversion to shared_ptrs these null checks will always pass.

Does anybody have a nice way of automatically detecting these cases:
if (foo == NULL) // when foo is a boost::shared_ptr 
?

We are not yet on C++11 but will be soon.

Example:

```
// declared elsewhere as :   boost::shared_ptr<T> foo;
if (NULL != foo) //always true when shared_ptr.  Correct check when raw pointer
{
      foo->DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: *"after conversion to shared_ptrs these null checks will always pass"* -- How do you figure?

Comment: Please check the following questions:

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621220/null-pointer-with-boostshared-ptr?rq=1
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266272/shared-ptr-null-pointer-and-assignment?rq=1
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431855/testing-if-a-shared-ptr-is-null?rq=1

Comment: How is NULL typed as in your system?   Find the definition and change it to something safer.

Comment: Can you show an example of such an always-passing check?

Comment: [Like this](http://ideone.com/OMretI)?

Comment: I've added an example snippet above

Comment: Try changing the #define of `NULL` to `nullptr` rather than 0, as this will aid in making sure pointers don't get implicitly converted to ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague provided this solution, which is pretty much exactly what I'm after:
Put into a common header (and added the parameters in reverse order as well)

```
template<typename T>
bool operator!=(int null, const boost::shared_ptr<T>& p)
{   
    typedef typename T::intentional_error error;
    return false;
}

template<typename T>
bool operator==(int null, const boost::shared_ptr<T>& p)
{
    typedef typename T::intentional_error error;
    return false;
}
```

Gives a compile time error at the location of all comparisons between shared_ptr and int.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert all the pointers to your class, which will encapsulate shared_ptr, and overload it's "operator==" function to detect NULL comparisons and count them, or handle them properly. You can either stick with this proxy class, or after counting (and for example dumping to the log file) all comparisons decide whether to switch to shared_ptr or not.

Comment: I like this and that: class X { private: struct Y {}; private std::shared_ptr<Y> s; } and forward inline/non inline functions to Y functions/data

Comment: This is one way to find them, but it's cumbersome to make the proxy class handle all the operators etc... rather than using the neatness of shared_ptrs drop-in replacement for raw pointers.  I'm looking for a way to always catch the problem when anyone in my team makes this kind of change, rather than a process that we must follow.

Comment: Well, spending some time on this proxy class is a one-time effort and you can be sure that none of such mistakes will be missed in the future. In general it is too complicated to be found by some methods of static code analysis, f.e. int* emptyPtr = NULL; if (aPtr == emptyPtr), or some complicated template code.

Answer (score -2):

if (foo) should work. Also if(foo.get()) works

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question, which has how to detect where this is checked in the first place.